# Captcha using Codeigniter is not working

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

my codeigniter captcha  is not displaying captcha images.

```
 public  function captcha_example(){
    $this->load->helper("captcha");
    $vals = array(
        'word'          => 'Random word',
        'img_path'      => base_url().'img/photos/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'img/photos/',
        'font_path'     =>  base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width'     => 150,
        'img_height'    => 30,
        'expiration'    => 7200,

    );

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    echo $cap['image'];
    //echo  $vals['img_url'];

    $this->load->view('captcha_view');
}
```

I am not getting what is wrong in this code...

Comment: Please include the error traceback (if any) and what you suspect to be the problem. Perhaps an image would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try in Controller:

```
$data['cap'] = create_captcha($vals);
$this->load->view('captcha_view', $data);
```

And then in view:

```
echo form_input($cap);
```

UPDATE**

Also don't use base url, simply

```
    'img_path'      => 'img/photos/',
    'img_url'       => 'img/photos/',
    'font_path'     =>  'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
```

Comment: Thanks! This script works without base_url... sorry for my English is my first language is Tajik.

Answer (score 2):

Controller: Captcha.php

class Captcha extends CI_Controller {

```
public  function captcha_example(){
    $this->load->helper("captcha");
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $vals = array(
        'word'          => 'Random word',
        'img_path'      => base_url().'img/photos/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'img/photos/',
        'font_path'     =>  base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width'     => 150,
        'img_height'    => 30,
        'expiration'    => 7200,

    );

    $data['cap'] = create_captcha($vals);
    $this->load->view('captcha_view', $data);
    //echo  $vals['img_url'];


}
```

}

View: captcha.php

```
echo form_input($cap);
```